# Consulta Mysql distict en sum?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta de Mysql en la que sumo datos de 2 tablas:

Tabla ventas:

```
ORDER_ID | PRODUCT_ID | TITULO | UNIDADES 

   50        A          LAPIZ         10  
   51        B          GOMA          30 

Tabla pagos

OPERACION_ID | VALOR | COSTO | IMPUESTOS

   51           100      50       20
   51           150      60       30
   50           80       30       10
```

Yo quisiera ver de cada articulo, las ventas (cada linea de la tabla ventas es una), unidades, valor total, costo total e impuestos total (puede haber mas de 1 pago por cada venta)

Hice lo siguiente:

```
select product_id, SUM(unidades) as suma_unidades, titulo, SUM(valor) as suma_monto, COUNT(product_id) as conteo_ventas, SUM(costo) as suma_costo, SUM (impuestos) as suma_impuestos 
 from ventas as ord 
 inner join pagos as pag ON (order_id=ord.operacion_id) 
 group by product_id order by titulo
```

El problema es que la suma de unidades y el conteo de ventas me lo duplica cuando hay 2 operacion_id con el mismo valor que order_id
Tendria que hacer una especia de distinct en esos valores, no se si exista algo asi (los demas los suma bien)

Quisiera que el resultado sea

```
A LAPIZ 1 venta, 10 unidades, 80 (valor), 30 (costo), 10 (imp)
B GOMA  1 venta, 30 unidades, 250, 110, 50
```

O sea, por producto, pero con el nexo entre ambas tablas el nro de orden y operacion (orden_id siempre unico, operacion_id pueden ser varias)

Comment: Lo que tenes que hacer es primero sumar pagos y luego usar esa tabla como ingreso a la otra..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes de hacer el uso de un subquery donde agrupes primero por operacion_id, haces las sumas correspondientes, le asignas un alias e integras el query con la otra tabla, en lugar de utilizar el INNER JOIN, por ejemplo:

```
 SELECT ord.p,
        ...,
        ...
 FROM   ventas AS ord, (SELECT SUM(x),
                               ...,
                               ...,
                               operacion_id 
                        FROM   pagos
                        GROUP BY operacion_id
                       ) AS pag
 WHERE ...
 GROUP BY ...
```